# Common neutral vs common earth in surge protection devices

Tags: surge-protection

I came across two different connectivity options for SPDs:

Option - 1: Common earth

[image: SPD option 1]

Option - 2: Common neutral

[image: SPD option 2]

Both of these types come from the same company. My observation is that most of the SPDs come in option - 1 configuration i.e. with a common earth.

The following is my understanding:

Common earth SPDs: Having earth as a return path makes a logical sense. We want the voltage spikes to be returned to earth. However, this can cause nuisance when installed downstream of any RCCB, especially when SPD is close to death. After taking a few hits, MOVs can start leaking some current to earth and causing the RCCB to trip. If they use GDTs that avoid leakage current, that's a different story but I have opened a couple of them and this wasn't the case. In one product, I found that they are using MOVs for line to neutral and then a GDT between neutral and earth. This however was an SPD with common neutral.

Common neutral SPDs: This avoids any nuisance tripping of RCCB because leakage current (if any) will return to neutral. Gives me flexibility during installation. I don't need to bother if I am installing this unit upstream or downstream of an RCCB. Most of the power supply circuits in household appliances, that do not use earth connection have MOVs placed across line and neutral so usage of common neutral makes sense. Besides, the major damage that occurs due to surges is in the power supply section. So having an external SPD that reinforces the circuit level surge protection seems to make a logical sense to me.

These are my questions:

1. Is there any standard that defines what option is preferred?
2. Is there any advantage/disadvantage (other than nuisance tripping) of any SPD option?
3. Can both SPDs be equally recommended for any installation?

Comment: The installation may not use earth bonded neutral. Try reading up on TN, IT and TT systems. I can't remember which one but, one doesn't earth neutral. You choose the SPDs to suit the installation.